# About to go ape - Changing email/username in Profile:Edit

Tags: cartthrob, profile-edit, mightybigrobot

I don't know what is going on with the guys over at MightyBigRobot, but I am getting extremely frustrated that I can't get an answer to this issue. I have a client withholding payment until this basic feature is working.

I have "Email as Username" enabled in Profile:Edit, but when a user updates their email address, it does not carry over to the native EE Member Username field so they cannot log in using their new email address, they have to continue to log in using their old one.

Can anyone give me some direction on how to get this working? I've emailed them, posted on their support forums and get nothing in return.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide! :-)

```
{exp:profile:edit return="account/profile/updated" class="validate"}
   <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span6">
       <label>E-Mail Address *</label>
       <input type="text" class="span12" name="email" value="{email}" required />
     </div>
   </div>

   <hr />

   <p><a href="{path='account/password'}">Click here to change your password</a></p>

   <hr />

   <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span6">
     <label>First Name *</label>
     <input type="text" name="member_first_name" value="{member_first_name}" class="span12" required />
     </div>

     <div class="span6">
     <label>Last Name *</label>
       <input type="text" name="member_last_name" value="{member_last_name}" class="span12" required />
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span6">
       <label>Company *</label>
       <input type="text" name="member_company" value="{member_company}" class="span12" required />
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span6">
       <label>Address *</label>
       <input type="text" name="member_address" value="{member_address}" class="span12" required />
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span5">
       <label>City *</label>
       <input type="text" name="member_city" value="{member_city}" class="span12" required />
     </div>

     <div class="span4">
       <label>State *</label>
       {exp:cartthrob:state_select name="member_state" selected="{member_state}" class="span12"}
     </div>

     <div class="span3">
       <label>Zip *</label>
       <input type="text" name="member_zip" value="{member_zip}" class="span12" required />
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span6">
       <label>Phone Number *</label>
       <input type="text" name="member_phone" value="{member_phone}" class="span12 phone" required />
     </div>
   </div>

   <hr />

   <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success" />
{/exp:profile:edit}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SUCCESS!!!!!!**

```
Admin > Security and Privacy > Security and Sessions > Allow members to change username
```

was set to NO! Changed it to yes and voila! Erghh.

Simple fix but should be documented somewhere!

Hope this helps someone out there!

Comment: Go ahead and mark this as your answer, Jacob. (makes for good expressionengine.stackexchange.com site karma to have more answered questions)

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me... Are you running the latest version of P:E?

Also, what does your login form look like? On my P:E login form I'm using

`<input type="text" name="username">`

and then on my P:E edit profile form I'm using

`<input type="text" name="email">`

the same as your code block.

Edit to add, I've tested using EE 2.5.5 and P:E 1.0.8, so not the most recent versions myself.

Comment: I am using 1.0.9 for P:E. I will check the code. Thx.

Comment: So when you run the profile:edit form to update the email address, you see that email address in the native EE Member Username field afterwards?

Comment: I am running 1.0.9 for P:E and 2.5.5 for EE. I wonder if it's an issue with 1.0.9? Any ideas where I could get 1.0.8 to troubleshoot?